# Problema con paquete 'summarytools' en R

Tags: r, rstudio, packages

una consulta, tengo un problema al cargar del paquete 'summarytools', al aplicar 'library(summarytools)' la respuesta es la siguiente:

Registered S3 method overwritten by 'pryr':
  method      from
  print.bytes Rcpp

Les ha pasado lo mismo con este u otros paquetes, agradezco su ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas advertencias son algo relativamente nuevo, creo que empezaron a aparecer  partir de R 3.60.

Es algo frecuente y se presenta cuando cargas una librería que tiene un método con el mismo nombre que otra que también se está cargando o ya se cargó. En este caso `summarytools` importa a `pryr` y a `Rcpp` y ambas tienen un método con el mismo nombre (el método `bytes` para `print` o `print.bytes`. Supongo que `pryr` se carga después que `Rcpp` y por eso sobreescribe el método.

En principio no hay problema, es sólo una advertencia de algo que está pasando y no se interrumpe la ejecución. En este caso `pryr` depende de `Rcpp` y es esperable que la superposición de nombres en los métodos sea "amistosa", conocida por los desarrolladores y no problemática. Así que puedes ignorarla, a menos que algo no esté funcionando como esperas.

Si te resulta molesto ver el mensaje puedes esconderlo con `suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(summarytools))`.

Y sí, pasa con otros paquetes. `tidyverse` genera una warning similar por métodos superpuestos en `rlang` y `ggplot`.

Comment: Lo he resuelto, con la actualización de R.3.60 en Mac es necesario instalar XQuartz, por error había desinstalado esta aplicación, al no estar disponible, Rstudio generaba se pagaba al ejecutar este tipo de paquetes con contienen dos métodos iguales, Muchas gracias!